# HttpContext.Current.Request is not available in RegisterGlobalFilters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add `RequireHttpsAttribute` attribute to `MVC filters collection` to push web site to HTTPS when it is deployed on prod server. The problem is with `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal` line, the `Request` object is not available yet. Then how to check is site running `localy` or on `prod` server in `RegisterGlobalFilters`?

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {    
        if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal) //Exception here!!!
        {
            filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this method you are to register the filters that will do the checking when the request comes in. This method will only get called once each time the application is started. So here you need to do something along the lines of:

```
filters.Add(new MyAuthorizeAttribute());
```

With MyAuthorizeAttribute being something along the lines of:

```
 public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        If(!httpContext.Request.IsLocal)
        {
            **//Check for HTTPS and return false if need be**
        }
}
```

Of course it does not need to be an AuthorizeAttribute.

**EDIT**

As I said before this method is called only once at the start of the application so there is no request for you to check in here. Here you can only apply filters that will be called every time a request is received. It is inside those filters that you can check request specific properties.

If you insist on using the RequireHttpsAttribute, than you either have to apply it to all methods regardless of whether the request is local or not or you have to extend RequireHttpsAttribute and override HandleNonHttpsRequest to handle local requests.

Comment: Sorry but I do not get your idea. How this can help me to find out is request Local in RegisterGlobalFilters and add RequireHttpsAttribute attribute to filters list?